# how to identity insert without while loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, identity

I need to insert one table's last inserted identity value into another table,
My database hit is very high, so bulk insert without identity insert will cause integrity problems.

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_tag_rule
(
    tag_rule_id     BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    version_batchid BIGINT,
    tag_id          BIGINT,
    rule_id         BIGINT  
)

CREATE TABLE tbl_version
(
    version_id      BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    version_batchid BIGINT,
    version_name    NVARCHAR(255),
    tag_rule_id     BIGINT
)
```

**I will pass below xml values to sp.**

```
'<root>
    <record version_batchid ="1" version_name="Apple">
        <item tag_id="1" rule_id="1"></item>
        <item tag_id="2" rule_id="2"></item>
        <item tag_id="3" rule_id="3"></item>
        <item tag_id="4" rule_id="4"></item>
    </record>
</root>'
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------+
| tag_rule_id | version_batchid | tag_id | rule_id |
+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------+
|           1 |               1 |      1 |       1 |
|           2 |               1 |      2 |       2 |
|           3 |               1 |      3 |       3 |
|           4 |               1 |      4 |       4 |
+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------+

+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
| version_id | version_batchid | version_name | tag_rule_id |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
|          1 |               1 | Apple        |           1 |
|          2 |               1 | Apple        |           2 |
|          3 |               1 | Apple        |           3 |
|          4 |               1 | Apple        |           4 |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Currently I am using while loop to get this done. Is there any other way to be inserted without a while loop,

Comment: Then you can use `Scope_indentity` and set it in variable then use it another table to insert

Comment: The only way you could avoid a loop is if there were some way to JOIN the two tables other than the Identity columns.   Your table structure doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  What's the point of having two tables if there is a different version for every rule?   Seems to me your XML should only create one row in `tbl_Version`

Comment: @KrishnrajRana That is what I'm currently doing I while loop , but I need to be inserted without while loop !

Comment: @TabAlleman : why because some version will be published or some version might be updated but a tag_rule is once created will not be changed or even updated.

Comment: So if there must be a 1-to-1 relationship of versions to rows, why have two tables?   Just add the `version_name` to the `tag_rule` table.

Comment: Hi Rahul, did my answer help you? Do you need any further help?

Answer (score 0):

With a query like this you get all needed data into a declared table variable: It should be easy to do the inserts from there into both tables. You might use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON` and insert with adding `SELECT MAX(id)+1` or you could write the fitting IDs back into the `@tbl`variable with an UPDATE statement...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(tbl_rule_id INT,VersionBatchID INT, VersionName VARCHAR(100),tag_id INT,rule_id INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY One.Item.value('@tag_id','int')) AS tbl_rule_id
        ,@x.value('(/root/record)[1]/@version_batchid','int') AS VersionBatchID
        ,@x.value('(/root/record)[1]/@version_name','varchar(max)') AS VersionName
        ,One.Item.value('@tag_id','int') As tag_id
        ,One.Item.value('@rule_id','int') As rule_id
FROM @x.nodes('/root/record/item') AS One(Item);

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

The result:

```
tbl_rule_id VersionBatchID  VersionName tag_id  rule_id
1           1               Apple       1       1
2           1               Apple       2       2
3           1               Apple       3       3
4           1               Apple       4       4
```

EDIT: A way how you could do the inserts, but surely that this needs adaptions for multiple inserts:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_tag_rule ON;
INSERT INTO tbl_tag_rule(tag_rule_id,version_batchid,tag_id,rule_id)
SELECT tbl_rule_id,VersionBatchID,tag_id,rule_id 
FROM @tbl; 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_tag_rule OFF;

SELECT * FROM tbl_tag_rule; 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_version ON;
INSERT INTO tbl_version(version_id,version_batchid,version_name,tag_rule_id)
SELECT tbl_rule_id,VersionBatchID,VersionName,rule_id 
FROM @tbl
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_version OFF;

SELECT * FROM tbl_version
```